# Laravel 7 - set timezone globaly, save as UTC

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Currently, I have set timezone as **Australia/Sydney**, `(TIMEZONE=Australia/Sydney)` and every **datetime** in DB is saved in this timezone. Is it possible to set timezone globaly, and save as UTC using elouqent?

Answer (score 0):

By default `created_at` and `updated_at` are Carbon objects so you can call `shiftTimezone('UTC')` carbon method on them.